# How to get top 3 sum of the table based on level in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, group-by, sum, laravel-8

I have table like this

[image]

i want to sum to get Total Team Score based on level and top 3 score based on score 1, score 2, score 3

> TOTAL SCORE TEAM = Top3 Score 1 + Top3 Score 2 + Top3 Score 3

Result i hope

[image]

Can anyone help me how to get the result in my controller and my blade?

Answer (score 0):

You should add Total score colum in your first colum then use this command to use this command to find whose score is highest level wise
`$result=[];`
`for($k =0; $k<3 ;$k++)`
`$result[$k]=Cliente::max('total_score')->where('level',++$k)`

Answer (score 0):

I test this example it's successful

```
$data = DB::table('group_table')
    ->select('team','level',DB::raw('sum(score1 + score2 + score3) as total'))
    ->groupBy('team','level')
    ->get();

return response()->json($data);
```

> DB

[image]

> Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much its really helping. but what if i want only sum top 3 score from score 1, score 2, and score 3. as en example in Team STARS Level 1 from your DB total will be 646 because:
TOTAL = [(Top 3 Score 1) + (Top 3 Score 2) + (Top 3 In Score 3)]
TOTAL = [(89 + 81 + 66)  + (80 + 73 + 71)  + (72 + 64 + 50)]