# How to sum only top 3 of every score based on level in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-8, rank

I have table like this

[image]

here my controller but it sum all score  from score1 + all score 2 + all score 3

```
$data = DB::table('group_table')
    ->select('team','level',DB::raw('sum(score1 + score2 + score3) as total'))
    ->groupBy('team','level')
    ->get();

return response()->json($data);
```

i want only sum top 3 score from score 1, score 2, and score 3. as en example in Team STARS Level 1 from your DB total will be 646 because:

```
TOTAL = [(Top 3 Score 1) + (Top 3 Score 2) + (Top 3 In Score 3)] 
TOTAL = [(89 + 81 + 66) + (80 + 73 + 71) + (72 + 64 + 50)]
```

i dont know how to take only top 3 score on each score 1, score 2, and score 3. can someone help me

Comment: How is this any different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73357064/how-to-get-top-3-sum-of-the-table-based-on-level-in-laravel), which received several answers none of which you have accepted?

Comment: Are you ok with raw queries since there is no user input? Also, can you share a DB fiddle of your table?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather complex requirement. You can do it using collection functions if you are willing to load the entire table in PHP memory:

```
$teamLevelScores = DB::table('group_table')->get()
   ->groupBy([ 'team', 'level' ])
   ->map(function ($teams, $teamId) {
        $sum1 = $teams->sortByDesc('score1')->take(3)->sum('score1');
        $sum2 = $teams->sortByDesc('score2')->take(3)->sum('score2');
        $sum3 = $teams->sortByDesc('score3')->take(3)->sum('score3');
        return $sum1+$sum2+$sum3;
   });
```

This should result in a two dimensional collection like e.g.

```
$teamLevelScores = [ 
   'STARS' => [
      1 => 646,
      // ...
   ]
   // ...
];
```

There might be ways to do it within the query but they are probably not simple or DBMS specific.

Comment: i got this error Unsupported operand types: int + Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

Comment: @MichaelRitung try the update. I forgot to put the column to sum